# Can avoid asking for a later start date?

Tags: job-offer, united-kingdom, germany, taxes, start-date

I am very stressed with this, thus I kindly ask for any help available.

I am working in Bavaria, Germany. I am seriously considering accepting an offer (should arrive by tomorrow) to work in London in another company. I told them that my notice period is 1 month. When we talked over phone to see what I expect from the offer, I informed them that the apartment I rent has 3 months of "notice period", and they said they'd like to have me onboard ASAP, and we agreed that I would speak to the landlord to see if I can leave earlier - which I did, not happening.

Now they will send me the offer, I will tell them that I have to wait 3 months, they might get a bit unsatisfied. Now, let's say I will accept it by end of October at the latest, which sets the start date at start of February.

The problem is that I have to do my tax declaration here in Germany, and for that I need the [Lohnsteuerbescheinigung](https://blog.dendax.com/en/what-is-a-lohnsteuerbescheinigung-when-will-you-receive-it), which the company sent me early in February 2019 for the year 2018. That document sums up my income and taxes withhold (I have no other income or property, only my job).

So, ideally, if my starting date was March, I would do the tax declaration in early February, wait a couple of weeks to receive the letter in my apartment in Germany, pay whatever tax I would have to pay, and leave the country.

However, I feel a bit afraid of asking to delay my starting date from Feb to March, and that's why I would like you to ask if see a way of my tax declaration happening without asking for a delay (i.e. having my start date in February)?

Comment: Thought: Assuming I start in London on 1 Feb. Think how the Lohnsteuerbescheinigung 2019 will look like by summing up every month's payroll, do the tax declaration in January (if possible). But then will the German tax office proceed with processing my tax declaration, or will they be blocked by awaiting for my company to send them the Lohnsteuerbescheinigung? If so, that means that the letter will be sent by them in February, and by default, it should go to my apartment in Germany. Maybe I could kindly ask if they could sent back to my parents' home in Greece...

Comment: " I informed them that the apartment I rent has 3 months of "notice period" Just because you have to give 3 months notice does not mean that you have to physically stay there for 3 months.

Comment: @sf02 indeed, however I am required to pay all 3 rents, so it'd be nice to also stay here for these 3 months. :) However, I see your point, which stresses that asking for a March starting date will make them frustrated...

Comment: just quit your rental with the 3 months notice, let the new company pay for the usused month, file your taxes in feb as everyone else and have the letter sent to the new living address. Make sure you report your move to the local 'Meldeamt' and let the relevant tax-bureau of your city know where to send the letters to..

Comment: @iLuvLogix you seem to have relevant knowledge, may I ask you to check my thought in the 1st comment and tell me what you think please? Maybe it's utterly rubbish.. :/ As for your comment, the new company did not - in any way whatsoever - imply that they would be pay for the unused months. How would I fill in my tax declaration from UK to Germany? When I did for 2018, I went physically to the Finanzamt, filled in the tax declaration (Steuererklärung). Thanks for helping. :) I am an early-career person, so any tips and points of view from you (experienced) guys is very valuable to me indeed..!!

Comment: if you work in the UK and your 'Hauptmeldewohnsitz'´is also there, you will need to pay relevant income taxes in the UK and according to their laws. You could still inform your german tax-bureau, but they can only tax you for what you've done until your move..

Comment: Reagrding the unused months: If the company really wants you you can try to negotiate a half-half deal. Another posssibility would be to present a properous 'Nachmieter' for your flat and hope the landlord will comply..

Comment: I'll get out of the office soon, if you like I can write up an answer to summarize everything once I get home and had dinner ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix by Hauptmeldewohnsitz you mean my tax residence? Searching the Internet didn't answer that. I wouldn't worry about that - if UK requires me to pay more taxes, this what I will simply do so, if you mean that. I don't have another person interested in the apartment. Moreover, except if they new company presses towards leaving before the 3 months, then I wouldn't like to rush things up, so ideally I wouldn't like to negotiate a half-half deal (that's a bit abstract). Yeah, be my guest, but certainly only if you have time and feel like it. But more importantly, check my initial comment.

Comment: Is there a break out clause in your rental contract? It may be that you can't leave early and pay nothing, but that you can get a reduced rate. Other option is if your landlord will let you sublet or find a replacement tenant.

Comment: No @Bee I have to pay 3 rents, in any case.

Comment: That is unusual and unlucky!

Comment: @Bee I don't know. However I am so not bothered by that 3 months, the contrary, I'd like the delay, in order to come closer to the date that I can make my tax declaration - but still I am short by 1 month before getting the "Lohnsteuerbescheinigung" (see question). To the Downvoter: If you think I can improve my question, please advice, if you think it's trivial, please tell me the solution. :)

Comment: From personal experience having moved countries a few times, it is entirely reasonable to ask your new employer to help you out with breaking your lease. Especially if they want you to start sooner rather than later.

Comment: @onnoweb but I don't want to do that! I want to stay here until I figure out my taxes and then leave.

Comment: @gsamaras Why are you so fixated on being physically in Germany to do your taxes? Just have the documents mailed to the UK and send your tax declaration by mail (or Elster). The Finanzamt will know how to contact you because you'll have to give them your new address when you de-register (using a form like [this one](http://www.muenchen.de/rathaus/dms/Home/Stadtverwaltung/Kreisverwaltungsreferat/fachspezifisch/HA-II/Buergerbuero/Dokumente/abmeldung_meldebehoerde.pdf)).

Comment: You are right @TooTea! However, I went today to the Finanzamt (in Ingolstadt), and they told me that I can submit my taxes either by physically going there or by sending them a letter - they did not mention Elster whatsoever, so I think I will need to go with the letter approach . .

Comment: I hope issue is solved now. Good luck for your future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tax Declaration**

You're making things more complicated than they actually are.

- If you have *Lohnsteuerklasse 1*, which is the default for singles, then the *Lohnsteuererklärung* is optional. You are likely to get money back, but there is no obligation to file it.
- You can do everything online via the Elster application. To avoid that you have to send a physical letter, you may request a certificate from https://www.elster.de. They will send you the details to your address in a few days.
- It helps to get the *Lohnsteuerbescheinigung* from your previous employer, but you can also sum up the numbers from your monthly pay statements.

**Apartement**

- Most landlords agree to let you go earlier, if you can find a suitable next tenant. Check if your landlord agrees to that.
- It's unlikely that you will use the full 3 notice period, because you need time to move out.

**Suggestion**

They want you to start with one month notice, but you're trying to postpone your start date for another 2 months, this will likely backfire, especially because you already mentioned your private issues.

If you really want the job, your next steps should be:

1. Request the Elster certificate immediately.
2. Discuss with your landlord if another tenant, which you will find, could take over the rent. If not, accept it as transition costs.
3. Start your new job as soon as possible.
4. Inform your previous employer about your new address.
5. Mid of next year, file your *Lohnsteuererklärung* via Elster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I went to the Finanzamt today and asked how can I submit the tax declaration, and they told me that you have to either come here physically, or  with a letter in Finanzamt's mailbox - they didn't mention Elster whatsoever.. Since [Elster](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elster_(Software)) seems to be a government site, it makes me wonder why they didn't mention it... :/

Comment: That's because Elster access has to be confirmed by a physical letter sent to your address. But I am sure there are ways around it. Look for a Buchhalter, tell them the situation and let them tell you how to proceed - the costs are minimal and they may be able to help get some more money you didn't know about - like a moving-to-Germany pauschal from when you first came there.

Comment: I think you also get *Lohnsteuerbescheinigung* in addition to the one you already got as you leave the company, *i.e.* during your notice period. Even if you don't, you can contact the *Finanzamt* that is responsible for your financial jurisdiction and request a copy to be provided - Google how to do that. In any case, unless you are self employed or made any grave mistakes, then in all likelihood doing your taxes will result in getting money back, because your taxes are already part of your *Lohn*.

Answer (score 1):

The apartment problem can easily be solved, can't you just find a "Nachmieter"? If you can't find someone fast enough, offer to cover 20% of the rent for the first 2 months?

It will cost you some money but better than paying 2 extra months of rent.

Comment: I am not interested in finding another person, but thanks. :)